# append query in asp from access

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have a query in access like this :

```
insert into table1
select * from table2
```

I want user to update the above query from asp web page. Table2 is a linked excel table in access where users update daily in excel.

At the end of the day, I want them to update it using the asp web page into main access database into table2. I tried the code below but i got error ` **An action query cannot be used as a row source'**

```
 <% set conn = create.object ("ADODB.connection")
 conn open "odbcconnectionname"
 sql = "appendquery"
 set rs = create.recordset ("ADODB.recordset")
 conn.rs sql, conn %>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: "Didn't work" I don't suppose you could be a little more specific could you? BTW when creating a question in Stackoverflow its prefered that you actually ask a question for sake of good form.

Comment: When user opens the web page, i want the data from table2 to be inserted in table1 but it didn't happen....i get error `An action query cannot be used as a row source`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Set objConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objConn.Open  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbfile & ";"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
cmd.CommandType = 4 ''adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "appendquery" ''stored query
cmd.Execute recs

Response.Write recs & " updated"
```

The error you are getting means more or less what it says, you must execute an action query, you cannot use it for a recordset.

Comment: Thanks..it works now with your code...is it possible to show a message like "Successfully updated your query" to user after update is done?